# What does x円マン状態 mean?

Tags: words

From google:

0円マン状態でコンビニでコーヒーを買ったら店員に壮大にふかれる

What does the マン mean here? Does it modify 円 or 状態? I'm guessing the latter since it obviously it doesn't represent 万, but I have no idea what it adds to the sentence.

Comment: それ、コンテクストがないと絶対誰にもわかんないです。 http://blog.livedoor.jp/umauma1/archives/cat_50016662.html `ちょっとパロディ。 


余ったボードで顔にはめる0円マンを作成。`...`ブースに4人座ってるのも狭いんで、0円マンで宣伝兼見学に。 `

Comment: Thanks, I saw it somewhere else and since it also appeared in google I thought it was a niche set phrase or something and didn't bother reading through the actual post. The other sentences make things a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think マン means man.

0円マン　==  a man who has 0yen.

Comment: So, how does a "a man who has 0 yen" buy coffee at a convenience store?

Comment: I don't know. More likely situation is,
0円マン状態でコンビニでコーヒーを買おうとしたら店員に壮大にくさされる

Comment: それなら、”０円マン”の意味を、もったいぶらずに、解説してくださいな。私と同様、何だろう？と思っているリーダーもいるだろうから。

Comment: 文脈読んだらわかると思うんで、もうちょっと頑張ってみたら・・・

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the link @chocolate posted, this マン is obviously *man* as in *Spider-Man* or *Superman*. 0円マン状態 is just "(appearing) as Zero-Yen-Man", an imaginary hero that has "0円" on his face.